# Changing 2 properties from state concurrently in React?

Tags: reactjs, state

Is there any implications of using the following:

```
someFunction(){
  this.setState({
     propertyA:true,
     propertyB:'some string'
  })
}
```

or should each property within state be changed with a separate event?

Comment: You could split your `setState` up into two separate ones and set `propertyA` and `propertyB` separately, but if you can set them at the same time, that is usually preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the ideal way to set state. `setState` is an async call, meaning that it will batch concurrent state updates into one call to prevent unnecessary renders.

So this:

```
someFunction(){
  this.setState({
     propertyA:true,
     propertyB:'some string'
  })
}
```

And this:

```
someFunction(){
  this.setState({
     propertyB:'some string'
  });
  this.setState({
     propertyA:true,
  });
}
```

Will produce the same results.